# Enable Corrs in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I tried to enable Cors in laravel 5.3. But it don't run.
I have tried many ways.
First, I tried to include middleware Cors and add to Kernel.php.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

Then, I used plugin `barryvdh/laravel-cors` but don't run.

Hopefully, someone will guide me or correct me.

Comment: Format your code please

Comment: Instead of kernel, I think you might want to add it as middleware

Comment: @ThomasMoors. Yup, i add it as middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the example on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

However, this middleware would perform its task after the request is handled by the application:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Perform action

        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

**In short:** add it to the `response`, not to the `request`